# C++ Proofofworklimit to bitcoinj util.DecodeCompactBits

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoinj, bitcoin-core-development, android, bitcoin-wallet-app

What is equivalent bitcoinj  util.DecodeCompactBits for below c++.

Cbignum(~uint256(0) >>32)

Cbignum(~uint256(0) >>20)

Cbignum(~uint256(0) >>23)

Cbignum(~uint256(0) >>22)